# AWS CLI Credentials: Should I have a .aws folder in each project directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have multiple applications on my computer, and multiple AWS CLI credentials set up. Should there be a .aws folder in each project directory? Or should there only be one at the root?

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app to AWS Lambda but not sure how to organize my AWS CLI credentials/config.

Comment: One, under `~/.aws/`, and then create multiple credentials profiles there, as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There should only be one in your home directory where you keep all your profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence).

Also consider using a tool like [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) to avoid having to store your secret keys in the `~/.aws` directory.